# Converting a json document array to an array of json documents

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have this array inside a JSON object document. The `IpAddresses` array has around 2.000 elements

```
{
   "IpAddresses": [
    "18.213.123.130/32",
    "3.217.79.163/32",
    "3.217.93.44/32",
    .
    .
  ] 
}
```

I want to convert it to this way:

```
[
    {
        "ipAddress" : "18.213.123.130/32"
    },
    {
        "ipAddress" : "3.217.79.163/32"
    },
    {
        "ipAddress" : "3.217.93.44/32"
    },
    .
    .
]
```

I am trying to do it by using json package in python

```
myArray = ["18.213.123.130/32",
           "3.217.79.163/32",
           "3.217.93.44/32"
          ]

ip_addresses = {item: "ipAddress" for item in myArray}
json_str_ip_adresses = json.dumps(ip_addresses)
print(repr(json_str_ip_adresses))
```

But the output I got is the following:

```
> python array-json.py
'{"18.213.123.130/32": "ipAddress", "3.217.79.163/32": "ipAddress", "3.217.93.44/32": "ipAddress"}
```

I am getting all my elements inside a JSON document, but what I want is to get every element inside `myArray` as a JSON document with an "ipAddress" key, something like this:

```
> python array-json.py
'{"ipAddress" : "18.213.123.130/32"}, {"ipAddress":"3.217.79.163/32", {"ipAddress":"3.217.93.44/32"}'
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension as:

```
ip_addresses = [{"ipAddress": item} for item in myArray]
```

Also, you don't need `json.dumps()` and `repr()` to convert back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = { "IpAddresses": [ "18.213.123.130/32", "3.217.79.163/32", "3.217.93.44/32" ] }
[{"ipAddress": i} for i in data["IpAddresses"]]
```

Result:

```
[{'ipAddress': '18.213.123.130/32'},
 {'ipAddress': '3.217.79.163/32'},
 {'ipAddress': '3.217.93.44/32'}]
```